# Modeling bespoke kitchen cabinets with varying frame, door & moulding sizes

Tags: modeling

I provide kitchen visuals and would like to learn in Blender (an example of what I am trying to model attached). I would like to know a good workflow to model this type of thing,  I need to be able to alter the cabinet sizes easily and the cabinets can have various framework sizes, door mouldings, height, depth etc, I cannot see any training videos on this type of thing. Any advice or links to training videos would be great. [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of Bezier curves and *Bevel Object* for this.

Design the sections of the mouldings and frameworks as separate objects.  You can recycle them and even keep them as a reusable library, possibly in a separate file for easy linking.

Create a bezier curve representing their shapes as desired, but leave a gap keeping shapes open for plain panels, so Blender is able to cap the fronts of the panels with surfaces automatically, despite having a custom bevel profile.

[image]

Create cabinets out of panels made from separate bezier curve objects with rectangular shapes. Make sure they are set as *2D*, and assign the correct *Bevel Object* for the desired framework.

Easily edit the bezier curve points for different dimensions and panel shapes, Blender will automatically take care to keep undistorted proportions for the frameworks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help Duarte, I will have a look at doing this, how would you then split the framework for adding a wood material where the grain is in different directions for the side rails and the top and bottom rails?

Comment: For those I use a different technique, since making a different material for grain directions is easier, I just make either separate objects for each board, ou use different splines within the same curve with different materials.