# Efficient way of extruding moulding shapes out of walls

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude

I have a model of an apartment, which is all of it a single connected mesh (the vertex for the floors connect with the ones on the wall, etc) and I wanted to extrude small mouldings at the bottom of each wall (0.1m high, 0.025m thick), where it connects the floor, such that the floor would also be pushed by the extruded mouldings. I've been looking around for methods that would introduce the least amount of vertices, and that altered the mesh as little as possible (keep the floor vertices connected to the walls, and the walls to each other). However, I only found solutions using booleans, or curves with bevels. I'm new to Blender, so I was hoping to learn ways of doing this within the Edit Mode of my object.

Here's my current process:

1. Knife tool to cut the top of the moulding

[image: blender capture where the knife tool is being used to cut an edge along the wall]

2. Adjust the height of one of the cut vertices to 0.1m, then scale-z x0 the rest of the cut vertices relative to the first one, to align them vertically

[image: blender capture where all the cut vertices are vertically aligned to 0.1m]

3. Extrude all of the cut faces that have the same normal

[image: blender capture where the moulding shapes at the bottom of one wall are being extruded 0.025m]

4. Knife tool to cut an edge along the adjacent wall, and merge the cut with the extruded mesh, to connect both

[image: blender capture where the knife tool makes a cut along the wall adjacent to the extruded faces, such that the sides of the extrusion connects to the wall]

5. Delete the floor vertices left behind the extruded area, which will result in unseen faces, and connect the other wall to the extruded area.

[image: blender capture where unseen vertices are being deleted, and the other side of the extrusion is connected to the adjacent wall]

I'm sure there's a better, easier method to achieve this, right? Deleting the original floor vertices in the last step also deletes the floor faces, which forces me to re-create them later. I could instead merge these extra floor vertices to the extruded ones, but the whole process feels very brittle and prone to create bad geometry, so I was hoping if anyone would have any tips on how to achieve this result in a better way. Doing this on multiple faces at the same time would be ideal.

Let me know if there's any more info I can provide, many thanks!

Comment: I'd argue that the efficient way of doing this is not as a single mesh, but as a separate object. Possibly using curves or whatever other technique is suitable for you. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178627/19307 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58567/19307

Comment: Thanks! I committed to extruding from within Edit Mode for this, but I'll take a look at those for reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the top of your moulding you can choose the front view, activate the knife and cut orthogonally and through the whole mesh (<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>):

[image]

For the floor edges, choose the top view and cut the different edges.Then select all the faces on the floor, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold* and snap on the vertices (it won't leave any interior faces):

[image]

Or do a simple extrude up and snap, then go into *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces*, remove these faces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Extrude manifold from the floor directly saves a lot of steps.

Answer (score 1):

Loop cut and extrude the bottom portion you want.  Select all of the new top corner edges and give a *Bevel Weight* to the edges (bevel weight appears as a blue edge in the viewport).

[image]

Then use a *Bevel* modifier with some extra segments to your liking, *Limit Method -> Weight*, and a Custom Profile.

[image]

Changing the profile will model your molding accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Problems with this method and Shade Smooth, since you wanted all one object.  Probably fixable with a very particular bevel profile that preserves Normals for one segment down the wall.  Also don't know how fiddly this would be with complex shapes, but as long as you can keep everything straight and only give bevel weight to that one edge loop I think it should be ok.

Comment: My mouldings are intended to be as low-poly as possible, so I ended up just extruding without bevels, but this is neat!